# Is FFmpeg the only thing I can use to compress video files?

Tags: laravel, ffmpeg

I am trying to use FFmpeg in my laravel application to compress video files. So whenever the user uploads their file it will automatically compress it. Sadly things have not been successful. I keep getting an error about not being able to load the ffprobe and I don't know what that means and I am getting aggravated. There is no legit tutorial on this at all. Is there anything else that I can use besides ffmpeg? Or can somebody please really help me on this? Thanks in advance
Code edited

```
 $FFMpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create([
        'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\lary\blog\ffmpeg\bin', // the path to the FFMpeg binary
        'ffprobe.binaries' => 'C:\xampp\htdocs\lary\blog\ffmpeg\bin', // the path to the FFProbe binary
        'timeout'          => 3600, // the timeout for the underlying process
        'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,   // the number of threads that FFMpeg should use
    ]);
```

Comment: You should post the details of the error, including example code that triggers it. ffmpeg is widely used and should be entirely possible to get set up, but we'd need *specific* questions and examples instead of a vague rant. See https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/45 for starters.

Comment: @ceejayoz look at my code? I followed this example here https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/laravel-ffmpeg now whats the problem?

Comment: ffprobe is an application built and installed with ffmpeg

Comment: @t5050 Have you installed ffmpeg and ffprobe per the instructions on https://github.com/pascalbaljetmedia/PHP-FFMpeg ? ("This library requires a working FFMpeg install. You will need both FFMpeg and FFProbe binaries to use it. Be sure that these binaries can be located with system PATH to get the benefit of the binary detection, otherwise you should have to explicitly give the binaries path on load.")

Comment: @t5050 are you saying that I have to download ffmpeg and ffprobe binaries on my machine?

Comment: @t5050 Yes, you have to have ffmpeg and ffprobe installed to use them...

Comment: Not on my computer just on laravel application all i did was "composer require pbmedia/laravel-ffmpeg
" and that's all. I'm thinking that's all I should do.

Comment: @ceejayoz  I'm going to put my laravel application on my hosting site. Is it still going to work? is the ffmpeg application going to work on my hosting site? I hope you understand what I'm asking. Thanks

Comment: "I'm thinking that's all I should do." No, you need ffmpeg / ffprobe installed anywhere you want the code to use them. "I'm going to put my laravel application on my hosting site. Is it still going to work?" If you install ffmpeg / ffprobe there, sure.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned - you need FFMPEG to get this whole thing running.

FFMPEG (cli version) contains 2 "programs" - probe and ffpeg itself, before you can compress a video, you need to "probe" it to get some basic information about it.

This will also work on your server IF you can install things on it and change file permissions (ffpeg executeables need chmod +x to run), otherwise you can search for other compression services and work with their API.

Comment: Okay great. Just one more question. Is this going to work when I have to put my Laravel application on my hosting site? Will I have to download anything again?

Comment: Hey I downloaded ffmpeg on my computer. I specified the path as told. I'm still getting "Unable to load ffprobe"  I just edited my code.

Comment: Yes, you will have to download ffmpeg again, and you need to specify the path of the ffmpeg binarys in the config, i recommend to create an .env variable for this.